# Where to save downloaded data that can't be recreated?

Tags: ios, ios5

I created magazine reader app that uses png images as pages. When user downloads magazine, all png images are downloaded and stored in Caches folder.

Problem with Caches is that files in there can be apparently deleted anytime. Since app is designed to be used in offline mode as well, re-downloading of missing pages is impossible.

I tried to save it into Documents folder but my app got rejected, this apparently is not proper place for them.

So my question is, where can I put them to make that iOS won't delete them? I don't need them to be backed up to itunes or synced or anything like that, I just need them to stay there until I remove them.

I tried looking into the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW27) but I could not find a category that would fit my needs, am I missing something trivial?

EDIT: I need to support iOS 4 as well

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Put it in the Libary Folder

> Handle support files
>
> —files your application downloads or generates and can recreate as needed—in one of two ways:
>
> In iOS 5.0 and earlier, put support files in the /Library/Caches directory to prevent them from being backed up
>
> In iOS 5.0.1 and later, put support files in the /Library/Application Support directory and apply the com.apple.MobileBackup extended attribute to them. This attribute prevents the files from being backed up to iTunes or iCloud. If you have a large number of support files, you may store them in a custom subdirectory and apply the extended attribute to just the directory.

Comment: what if I want to support iOS 4.0 as well? I can't use that extended attribute in that case, can I? Only remaining option would be to put it into Caches folder and that means they will get deleted

Comment: What if I save those files into Application Support and mark them only if I am on 5.0.1 or higher, would that work? Will apple approve this solution?

Answer (score 2):

Apple has a tech note that addresses this at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html

It shows sample code for setting a no-backup attribute on files.